Strange behaviour with ax.get_xlim and date axis with matplotlib
I worked with temporal data and matplotlib before, so I know that in matplotlib, dates are represented as the number of days since epoch as a float, and that I can use matplotlib.dates to convert dates back and forth to floats.
Nevertheless, I encountered a pretty strange problem when using an API.  I want to create a function to decorate the plot with some temporal annotations, but I don't want to print the ones that are outside the plot. For example, if the plot goes back to 2020, I don't want to print an annotation in 2019. For that I used ax.get_xlim() and converted the limits to date with mdates.num2date.
When I plot a DataFrame with a DateTimeIndex ranging from 2019 to 2024, I get the limits (2599.0, 2860.0), which converted back to date is nowhere near 2019 or 2024.
The code is the following:
pytrends = TrendReq()
pytrends.build_payload(kw_list=['matplotlib', 'seaborn'])
df = pytrends.interest_over_time()
print(df.index)
df.plot()
print(plt.gca().get_xlim())

Which results in:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-20', '2019-10-27', '2019-11-03', '2019-11-10',
               '2019-11-17', '2019-11-24', '2019-12-01', '2019-12-08',
               '2019-12-15', '2019-12-22',
               ...
               '2024-08-18', '2024-08-25', '2024-09-01', '2024-09-08',
               '2024-09-15', '2024-09-22', '2024-09-29', '2024-10-06',
               '2024-10-13', '2024-10-20'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=262, freq=None)
(np.float64(2599.0), np.float64(2860.0))


I could not reproduce it with a simpler DataFrame.

Does this answer work for you? Things might work different depending on the environment and backend used.

Possibly, the xlim is only set once the plot is fully created.  Maybe calling plt.draw() before ax.get_xlim() works in your case?  Or you might try to extract the date range from the dataframe instead of from the plot? Note that the code in your post is not reproducible.

Nop, num2date returns something in the 70's. I also tried calling plt.draw() before. I'm going to go with extracting the date range from the dataframe, but other times I was able to extract it using num2date

For me it was working when the data is plotted via plt.plot(df) instead of df.plot(). It seems like pandas is submitting some strange formatting?!?

It seems that the axis is using a pandas.plotting._matplotlib.converter.PeriodConverter. Instead of converting the xmin, xmax back to the original type, I will just convert the things I am comparing them with using .convert()

The problem is not with Matplotlib, but with Pandas. It turns out that instead of using matplotlib's mdates, it is using a custom converter called PeriodConverter
If I drop one of the rows, then it uses an mdates converter. My solution was to use ax.convert_xunits() in the function that decorates the plot:
def add_events(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
        
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

    # Use enumerate to get same color in line and text
    for i,e in enumerate(EVENTS, 1):
        if not (xmin <= ax.convert_xunits(e.date) <= xmax):
            print(f"Skipping event {e.label}")
            continue

        ax.axvline(x=e.date, color=f'C{i}', linestyle='--', alpha=.5)
        ax.text(
            e.date,
            .5, # 50% from top
            e.label,
            color=f'C{i}',
            ha='left',
            va='top',
            transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform(),
            rotation=rotation,
        )

